# Python sort out columns in DataFrame for OLS regression

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, linear-regression

I have a csv file with the following columns:

Date|Mkt-RF|SMB|HML|RF|C|aig-RF|ford-RF|ibm-RF|xom-RF|

I am trying to run a multiple OLS regression in python, regressing 'Mkt-RF', 'SMB' and 'HML' on 'aig-RF' for instance.

It seems like i need to first sort out the DataFrame from the arrays but i cannot seem to understand how:

*# Regression*

```
x = df[['Mkt-RF','SMB','HML']]
y = df['aig-RF']
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y})
df['constant'] = 1
df.head()
sm.OLS(y,df[['constant','x']]).fit().summary()
```

The full code is:

*import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from sklearn import linear_model
import statsmodels.api as sm*

def ReadFF(sIn):
    """
    Purpose:
        Read the FF data

```
Inputs:
    sIn     string, name of input file

Return value:
    df      dataframe, data
"""
df= pd.read_csv(sIn, header=3, names=["Date","Mkt-RF","SMB","HML","RF"])
df= df.dropna(how='any')

# Reformat the dates, as date-time, and place them as index
vDate= pd.to_datetime(df["Date"].values,format='%Y%m%d')
df.index= vDate

# Add in a constant
iN= len(vDate)
df["C"]= np.ones(iN)

print(df)

return df
```

def JoinStock(df, sStock, sPer):
    """
    Purpose:
        Join the stock into the dataframe, as excess returns

```
Inputs:
    df      dataframe, data including RF
    sStock  string, name of stock to read
    sPer    string, extension indicating period

Return value:
    df      dataframe, enlarged
"""
df1= pd.read_csv(sStock+"_"+sPer+".csv", index_col="Date", usecols=["Date", "Adj Close"])
df1.columns= [sStock]

# Add prices to original dataframe, to get correct dates
df= df.join(df1, how="left")

# Extract returns
vR= 100*np.diff(np.log(df[sStock].values))
# Add a missing, as one observation was lost differencing
vR= np.hstack([np.nan, vR])

# Add excess return to dataframe
df[sStock + "-RF"]= vR - df["RF"]
print(df)

return df
```

def SaveFF(df, asStock, sOut):
    """
    Purpose:
        Save data for FF regressions

```
Inputs:
    df      dataframe, all data
    asStock list of strings, stocks
    sOut    string, output file name

Output:
    file written to disk
"""
df= df.dropna(how='any')

asOut= ['Mkt-RF', 'SMB', 'HML', 'RF', 'C']
for sStock in asStock:
    asOut.append(sStock+"-RF")

print ("Writing columns ", asOut, "to file ", sOut)


df.to_csv(sOut, columns=asOut, index_label="Date", float_format="%.8g")

print(df)
return df
```

def main():

```
sPer= "0018"
sIn= "Research_Data_Factors_weekly.csv"
sOut= "ffstocks"
asStock= ["aig", "ford", "ibm", "xom"]

# Initialisation
df= ReadFF(sIn)
for sStock in asStock:
    df= JoinStock(df, sStock, sPer)

# Output
SaveFF(df, asStock, sOut+"_"+sPer+".csv")
print ("Done")

# Regression
x = df[['Mkt-RF','SMB','HML']]
y = df['aig-RF']
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y})
df['constant'] = 1
df.head()
sm.OLS(y,df[['constant','x']]).fit().summary()
```

What exactly do i need to modify in pd.DataFrame in order to get the multiple OLS regression table?

Comment: What is the specific problem with the existing code? Reading through, I notice you're trying to assign multiple columns (`['Mkt-RF','SMB','HML']`) to the name `'x'`, where you should be able to pass those columns directly into a multiple linear regressor, without renaming them.

Comment: There are a few methods for the multiple OLS regression but i am following this example from [link] (http://rlhick.people.wm.edu/posts/estimating-custom-mle.html) so i am still confused as to how to pass the columns directly. It seems like everything is to be done in df = pd.DateFrame({, }) but can't figure out how.

Comment: I have changed to df = DataFrame(y, x) but the problem is in  sm.OLS(y,df[['constant','x']]).fit().summary() i get KeyError: "['x'] not in index".
i am trying to append the columns of 1 to the x dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose to change the first chunk of your code to below (mostly just swapping line orders):

```
# add constant column to the original dataframe
df['constant'] = 1

# define x as a subset of original dataframe
x = df[['Mkt-RF', 'SMB', 'HML', 'constant']]

# define y as a series
y = df['aig-RF']

# pass x as a dataframe, while pass y as a series
sm.OLS(y, x).fit().summary()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I added modified your last line into results = sm.OLS(y, x).fit() and print(results.summary()) but still get a an OLS regression results full of nan

Comment: @user304663 OK, but at least you are facing a new problem so that's a progress. I have no clue about your data, so I guess I cannot efficiently help you further. Have you confirmed that all your "x" variables are numeric?

Comment: Thank you your code helped anyway, i had an issue with my data!